# Magento Limit discount amount

Tags: magento

I have to limit the discount amount. that is, if subtotal above Rs.750 then i have to give 25% discount, but the maximum discount amount is Rs.200, I don't know how to do this. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Shopping cart price rules with No coupon and by selecting subtotal condition.

Here is the detail explanation: 
http://stuntcoders.com/learn-magento/prices-and-promotion/adding-shopping-cart-price-rule/

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but my condition is if the subtotal is Rs.750 than the discount is 25% not a Rs.200.. if discount is not exists more than Rs. 200

Comment: The example you gave in the URL does not solve the question.